# Transition of Z2 gauge theory in four dimensions

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, gauge-theory

Are there rigorous results (apart from the self-duality of the system and its self-dual transition point) concerning the character of the transition of the Ising lattice gauge theory in four dimensions?

Comment: The question is written for people with some knowledge of mathematical physics, so I understand folks from other areas of math might wonder if this is math, clear, interesting etc. In this case the question is about mathematics related to the Yang-Mills Clay Millenium problem and I think is totally fine for this site. I agree though that perhaps more pedagogical explanation might make it accessible to a wider audience and I would encourage @user153388 to edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The latest result on the model is by Malin Forsström:

["Decay of correlations in finite Abelian lattice gauge theories"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.03752)

which applies to finite Abelian gauge groups and in particular $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. It proves exponential decay of two point functions in some regime with regards to the coupling ($\beta\ge 0.4$ if I understood correctly).
To review the literature on rigorous results for Wegner's Ising discrete lattice gauge theory, one can look at the references in the article by Forsström, in particular the ones by Fröhlich-Spencer, Borgs and Chatterjee. One can also start with the article by Fröhlich-Spencer (covers $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}$ with $N$ large) and look up papers which cite it on say Google Scholar.